Why are 'wallet' and 'e-wallet' tagged as synonyms?
I admit I don't fully understand the tagging system, but we seem to have 'wallet' and 'e-wallet' tagged as synonyms. They have nothing whatsoever to do with each other. The tag 'wallet' is for questions about the Bitcoin wallet system used by the client, or at least that's what its description says. Whereas 'e-wallet' is the name used for services that provide you a notional wallet with a web-based (or text message or whatever) front end.
Is this just an error? How can it be corrected?

Certainly looks like an error. I don't know how to correct it though. Dori?

Synonyms.
Ask Dori ;-)

I also disagree with code → development synonym. (But it's not finalized)

That's a fair point. "Development" can refer to development of algorithms or methods as well as code. And questions about why existing code does a particular thing should be tagged "code" but doesn't have much to do with development.

I think source/programming should likely be synonyms. Development could go either way depending on whether it means just code development or also concept development. It shouldn't include business development, certainly.
